# Is there a limit on how large a number np.random.normal(0, 1) can generate?

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm basically wondering if it would be possible for RNG to generate a number in the thousands (with mean = 0, var = 1 as inputs). I get that it's basically impossible mathematically, but theoretically there is no such thing as a zero chance, is there a limit in reality though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In practice, numbers are first generated uniformly randomly (which we're [pretty good at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xoroshiro128%2B)), and then transformed to the target distribution. For 1D values, you can safely assume the `np.random.normal` uses inverse mapping from uniform `[0, 1]` to the quantile function of `normal`, so if the initially generated number is for example `0.000001`, the resulting, returned value, would be cca `-4.75`. For the result to be `-1000` (and not straight-up infinity, which of course is never returned), your [initial uniform-random number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-500000%29%20%2F%20sqrt%282*pi%29) would need to be cca `2.3 * 10^(-200000)` (an ultra-small number, hardly represented in python or c++). The most you could get (from a theoretically infinitesimal float) is around `-350`, but note that the probability is probably not worth discussing.